# Insert new heading above first heading in Google Docs without breaking hyperlinks

Tags: google-docs

Suppose I have a Google Docs document with some headings, and I have sent out an email with a hyperlink to the first heading in the document:

> `https://docs.google.com/document/d/` *AbTVfZtAPbMJeD08LDgV1QaPeQqm5giEoqoeqzgR6NHP* `/edit#heading=` *h.9thvmkhwr58r*

In the hyperlink, the first string of random letters identifies the document - second string of random letters identifies the heading.

How do I (manually or programmatically) insert a new heading above this heading, without changing the ID of the existing heading?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to achieve this manually.

1. Example document with "Heading foo" (h.68hwuix3y3s4) and "Heading bar" (h.3h7fjygeosfl, not shown)

   [image: document with "Heading foo" and "Heading bar". The cursor is on "Heading foo" and shows the id h.68hwuix3y3s4 in the address bar]
2. Create a new heading BELOW the current top heading. Here "Heading baz" (h.fbz5u461spta)

   [image: same document but with "Heading baz" below "Heading foo". The cursor is on "Heading baz" and shows the id h.fbz5u461spta in the address bar]
3. Use the mouse to select the old heading including the line break at the end. (Note, this will show the "wrong" id in the address bar)

   [image: same document with "Heading foo" selected]
4. Use the mouse to drag-drop the old heading to the start of the line below the new heading

   [image: same document but with "Heading foo" and "Heading baz" swapped]
5. Verify that the new and old headings have kept their ids

   [image: same document with the cursor on "Heading baz", showing that the id hasn't changed]

   [image: same document with the cursor on "Heading foo", showing that the id hasn't changed]